# PDO UPDATE not updating - no error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to this PDO stuff, I've got it working using SELECT but can't get UPDATE to work, hopefully I'm missing something simple here?

Help gratefully appreciated!!

Jon

```
$id = $intSessionUser;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['email'])) : null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['password'])) : null;

$strSql = "UPDATE user2 SET user_email = :email, user_password = :password WHERE user_id = :id";
echo $strSql;

$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);

$STH->bindParam(':id', $id);
$STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
$STH->bindParam(':password', $password);
$STH->execute();
$missing = "Login details updated";
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. You should show your database structure.

Comment: `$strSql = '...';` and then `$DBH->prepare($SQL)` maybe this? ;)

Comment: Related: `strip_tags($_POST['password'])`? Why??

Comment: What about commit? Do you use autocommit or do you need to commit it per transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preparing the wrong sql?

replace

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
```

by:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare($strSql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are preparing $SQL when it should be your $strSql? Also where do you define $DBH?

Answer (score 0):

The way `PDO` works , by default error are silent, probably for security reasons.

You have to tell `PDO` to throw error:

```
// If there is an error executing database queries, we want PDO to know
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Other than that :

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
```

should maybe be

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare($strSql);
```

Hope this helps